# Metamask not connecting to ganache localhost

Tags: metamask, ganache, ganache-cli

I am running a local `ganache-cli` and my metamask in my browser just keeps saying:

```
Oops! Something went wrong.
```

[image]

Here are the network details:

```
name: Localhost
RPC URL: http://localhost:8545
Chain ID: 1337
```

This started happening literally today, never had issues with it before. I don't *think* I changed any settings that would have affected this. I was just testing smart contracts locally like I normally do.

And my ganche-cli reflects this. I even make the JSON-RPC call for chainId, and this is correct.

Here is what I've tried:

1. Switching browsers (brave -> chrome)
2. Changing ports  on both the ganache-cli, UI, and metamask
3. Changing RPC_URL (to `localhost`, `0.0.0.0`...) on both the ganache-cli, UI, and metamask
4. Using the [ganache app](https://www.trufflesuite.com/ganache)
5. Uninstalling and reinstalling browsers
6. Uninstalling and reinstalling metamask
7. Turning computer off and on again
8. Resetting account in the advanced config

I'm losing my mind. I am able to deploy contracts to the ganache chain via the command line.

Here is what else I've looked at:
[Metamask not connecting to localhost](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29330/metamask-not-connecting-to-localhost)
http://asifwaquar.com/connect-metamask-to-localhost/
https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues

Comment: Do you have other extension that may cause problems? I've the same configuration with Metamask on Firefox and Chrome without issues. Sometimes "reset account" in the Advanced menu fixed some odd issues with Metamask and ganache.

Comment: Yep :( Tried that too.

Comment: Just for reference I've just tested with Ganache CLI v6.12.1 (ganache-core: 2.13.1) under node v12.20.0 with Metamask v9.1.1 and it worked.

Comment: my ganache get always 5777 as  network id, can you change it to that

Comment: Yep :( I get `The endpoint returned a different chain ID: 1337`

Comment: What operating system are you using? Are you sure the localhost:8545 is reachable?

Start with:
$  ganache-cli --networkId 4711

Check with:
$ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"net_version","params":[],"id":67}' localhost:8545
{"id":67,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"4711"}

Comment: MacOS. Yes, I was able to make JSON-RPC calls with ease. It returned the proper chainId

Comment: I'm assuming if we find out what API call metamask is making, we can probably test that and see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.

Both my Brave browser and Google Chrome were having issues. I tested then on firefox and it worked fine. A reinstall of Google Chrome fixed the issue for Chrome. A reinstall of Brave did not fix it.

Looks like it's an issue with Brave Browser. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you can really access your ganache-cli on localhost:8545 and the network id is 1337. Metamask asks for 'net_version' when connecting to the blockchain.

1. Start Ganache with:

```
$  ganache-cli --networkId 1337
```

2. Check with:

```
$ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"net_version","params":[],"id":67}' localhost:8545
```

expected result:

```
{"id":67,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"1337"}
```

Comment: Yep, tried this.

Comment: Was it successful?

Comment: The expected result from your answer yes, but metamask is still giving the same error from my original question

Comment: What operating system are you using? Did you try a clean install of Metamask with Firefox?

Comment: MacOS. Yes, uninstall and reinstalled metamask, and tried it on a few browsers

Comment: You may try a docker ganache. This is a ganache-cli with automatic compile and deploy of some contracts. I use this image since more than a year in a complex blockchain project as test container. I'm 100% sure that this ganache work on MacOS, Linux and Windows 10. Just use and wait till the maven build is ready: 
docker run -p 8545:8545 ihkmuenchen/cbc-contracts-ganache:4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that metamask could not connect to my page. But in my case, I ran `truffle migrate --reset` and got back `zsh: command not found: truffle` and thus after `npm install -g truffle`, I ran `truffle migrate` and refreshed my page and it worked.