# Can't see the balance of my ETH when in Localhost 8545

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask

i'm using a go ethereum node, version 1.10.11. But when I'm on metamask, my balance only shown when it's on Ethereum Mainnet but when I change it to Localhost 8545, it doesn't show. I tried to edit the details of the Localhost network but as shown in the pictures is my concern. Please help, thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Each network  has it's own chain id. [How to select a network id or is there a list of network ids?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17051/how-to-select-a-network-id-or-is-there-a-list-of-network-ids/17101) here is a list with the chain id's for each network. Regarding your problem, you could  try setting the chain id to 1337 in your Metamask for localhost:8545(you'll have to start ganache-cli for it  to work). Alternatively,if this doesn't work, when you start ganache, you can set the chain id in the terminal:
Ex: `ganache-cli --chainId 1337`

Afterwards, you can set it in your Metamask and it should work. [Metamask not connecting to ganache localhost](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/94301/metamask-not-connecting-to-ganache-localhost). This is a more detailed overview.